# Why does spring boot application running on embedded tomcat shut downs automatically after 1-2 hours on ubuntu 14.04 aws VM?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I deploy my spring-boot application using
`mvn spring-boot:run>server.log&` or `java -jar target/myapp.jar>server.log&`

I am having this problem on one instance only, that after I start my app, everything is working fine and a few hours later the application automatically shuts down. `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: IS_SECURITY_ENABLED` started to show when i changed my pom from using undertow to tomcat. But besides this error also my application starts and everything works fine. As seen below in the logs the application started at 11:42 and was running fine till 13:11 then automatically shuts down at 14:01

The only thing different in this instance from others is that I have enabled MongoDB Authentication  in this one, but I am able to successfully connect and perform operations using my Spring Application. So this doesn't seem to be the issue.

```
2016-08-12 11:42:06.334  INFO 10655 --- [           main] c.m.s.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner       : Created resource listing Path: /v1/store-test-controller Description: store-test-controller Position: 0
2016-08-12 11:42:06.726  INFO 10655 --- [           main] c.m.s.core.SwaggerApiResourceListing     : Added a resource listing with (4) api resources: 
2016-08-12 11:42:06.728  INFO 10655 --- [           main] c.m.s.core.SwaggerApiResourceListing     :   Basic Error Controller at location: /api-docs/v1/basic-error-controller
2016-08-12 11:42:06.728  INFO 10655 --- [           main] c.m.s.core.SwaggerApiResourceListing     :   Store Admin Controller at location: /api-docs/v1/store-admin-controller
2016-08-12 11:42:06.728  INFO 10655 --- [           main] c.m.s.core.SwaggerApiResourceListing     :   Store Controller at location: /api-docs/v1/store-controller
2016-08-12 11:42:06.728  INFO 10655 --- [           main] c.m.s.core.SwaggerApiResourceListing     :   Store Test Controller at location: /api-docs/v1/store-test-controller
2016-08-12 11:42:06.782  INFO 10655 --- [           main] org.mortbay.log                          : Logging to Logger[org.mortbay.log] via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
2016-08-12 11:42:06.799 ERROR 10655 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : StandardWrapper.Throwable

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: IS_SECURITY_ENABLED
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspRuntimeContext.(JspRuntimeContext.java:197)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.init(JspServlet.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.deferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.startConnector(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:217)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:154)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
    at com.XXXXXXXXX.XXXXXXXXXXXApplication.main(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXApplication.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2016-08-12 11:42:06.800 ERROR 10655 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Servlet [jsp] in web application [] threw load() exception

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: IS_SECURITY_ENABLED
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspRuntimeContext.(JspRuntimeContext.java:197)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.init(JspServlet.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1038)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext.deferredLoadOnStartup(TomcatEmbeddedContext.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.startConnector(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:217)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:154)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
    at XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXApplication.main(XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXApplication.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2016-08-12 11:42:06.800  INFO 10655 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-08-12 11:42:06.804  INFO 10655 --- [           main] XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXApplication    : Started XXXXXXXXXXApplication in 9.466 seconds (JVM running for 15.018)
2016-08-12 11:42:12.464  INFO 10655 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-08-12 11:42:12.465  INFO 10655 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-08-12 11:42:12.475  INFO 10655 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 10 ms
2016-08-12 11:46:25.459  INFO 10655 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] c.n.s.s.impl.StoreCustomerServiceImpl    : UPDATE:: Customer Found Updating
2016-08-12 11:47:05.382  INFO 10655 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.n.s.s.impl.StoreCustomerServiceImpl    : UPDATE:: Customer Found Updating
2016-08-12 11:47:41.494  INFO 10655 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.n.s.s.impl.StoreCustomerServiceImpl    : UPDATE:: Customer Found Updating
2016-08-12 13:11:02.357  INFO 10655 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.n.s.s.impl.StoreCustomerServiceImpl    : UPDATE:: Customer Found Updating
2016-08-12 14:01:55.661  INFO 10655 --- [       Thread-4] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@a68229f: startup date [Fri Aug 12 11:41:57 UTC 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-08-12 14:01:55.664  INFO 10655 --- [       Thread-4] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2016-08-12 14:01:55.677  INFO 10655 --- [       Thread-4] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2:20:02.877s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Aug 12 14:01:55 UTC 2016
```

pom.xml

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>XXXXXXXX</groupId>
<artifactId>XXXXXXXXX</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.jcip</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcip-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.2</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Could it be the Linux Low Memory Process Killer ? Anything in the system logs?

Comment: You're having 2 versions of `neo4j-cypher-compiler` (2 jars). try first to remove one of them